# Печать в PHP по IPP

Tags: php, cups

Мне нужно из php отправлять на печать на локальный принтер. Нашел такое решение - [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://github.com/smalot/cups-ipp)

Получаю список принтеров (у меня их 2) и очереди печати. Но не могу создать свою печать. Получаю ошибку - Unauthorized

Если кто сталкивался - помогите, я впервые с таким работаю и уже не знаю, что можно еще сделать

Comment: а какой собственно принтер? Он пиишет что вы не авторизованны, значит надо запросить авторизацию, потом с ключем стучаться к принтеру

Comment: Жесть, уже принтеры авторизацию просят. Скоро даже пылесосить нельзя будет. Сорь за оффтоп))